# Ajax Requests Failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

The Post requests stay pending. 
I wanted to log the JSON body of the incoming request.
The request works when using Postman but the AJAX requests dont work

Node Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 3000;

var app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));

var qRouter = express.Router();
qRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

qRouter.route('/')
.all(function(req,res,next) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      next();
})
.post(function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  res.end("lalal");
})
app.use('/play',qRouter);

app.listen(port, hostname, function(){
console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

AJAX REQUEST

```
    var d = {
    "rating": 5,
    "comment": "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        "author": "Paul McVites"
  }

  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/play',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(d)
  });
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? surely there's an error or some indicator.

Comment: The requests always stay pending, idk why

Comment: and what functions within node are being called in what order?

Comment: all and then post?

Comment: is that a guess? or did you open a debugger. because if both of those callbacks were called, it wouldn't still be pending.

Comment: Logged it. It was in this order only

Comment: did the request body contain what it should when logged?

Comment: The request works fine till the call of next function. There seems some problem in the post function

Comment: What does req.method give you? my guess is "OPTIONS", which would mean you didn't pay close enough attention to the network tab (and would explain why .post callback never gets called and the request stays pending)

Comment: Yup. After some time it shows OPTIONS

Comment: then you need to handle options requests. if it's an options request, end it, otherwise go on to the post.

Comment: But why is it using options request instead of post? Sorry, it's my first time using node

Comment: because that's what happens when you send a CORS request with a different than default content type. This isn't node related.

Comment: So I have to make a different Handler for options?

Comment: that or just handle it in the all.

Comment: Logging req.body in all is also displaying an empty array

Comment: As it should, option requests don't have a body. **Research CORS please**.

Comment: Then can you provide another possible solution for sending data?

Comment: did you research CORS? because if you did you would know the limitations of sending data between two different origins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a CORS-related issue. Solved earlier by starting the frontend and backend on the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not handling your the response of your ajax call with jQuery. You are sending the data, but I don't see you receiving the server response. POSTMAN handles this automatically for you.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem.